# Can "respectively" be used to refer to more than two items in a series?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is the following a proper use of "respectively"? And if it is not, what is the proper construction of this sentence:

> Counts 10, 12, and 14 of the indictment charged Mr. Client, along with Mr. Co-client, with First Degree Murder While Armed (Premeditated), in violation of D.C. Code §§ 22-2101, 4502, 2104.01(b)(4), 2104.01(b)(6) (2001 ed.). Counts 11, 13, and 15 charged Mr. Client, and Mr. Co-client, with Possession of a Firearm During a Crime of Violence or Dangerous Offense, in violation of  D.C. Code § 22-4504(b) (2001 ed.). Each of those counts related to one of the homicide charges.
>       Count 18 of the indictment charged with Mr. Client with Carrying a Pistol Without a License, in violation of D.C. Code § 22-4504(a) (2001 ed.). Count 29 charged Mr. Client with Obstruction of Justice, in violation of D.C. Code § 22-722(a)(6) (2001 ed.).
>       When the charges were submitted to the jury, the above listed charges were respectively renumbered 1-6 and 8-9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a proper use of *respectively,* although it's a monster paragraph. *Respectively* can certainly refer to more than two things, and each list is just married up.

> **respectively** *adverb*
>       separately or individually and in the order already mentioned (used when enumerating **two or more items or facts** that refer back to a previous statement)
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respectively) (my emphasis)

Comment: It will put any two sets with the same finite number of elements into 1-1 correspondance, **provided** they are each pronounced (or written) fully, each in the appropriate order. This tends to limit the utility of the method for large sets, especially in speech.